# How to properly save self reference with ES6 classes?

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

Honestly, I'm not sure of what is the cause for the behavior: systemjs, babel or my own fault. I'm using class for custom control controller and saving class reference in self variable. Apparently that gets overriden by any subsequent controller instances.

I created a simple repository to demonstrate:
clone, install, run live-server or your preferred server. You will see 2 buttons, each is a custom control. Clicking on a button only affects one control.

https://github.com/alexkolt/selfIsThis

How can I get this working with ES6 class?

Comment: You have one `self` for all controller instances. What's the point of `self` anyway?

Comment: Please post your code (or the relevant parts of it) in your question, instead of linking some github repo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not really using ES6 classes right. You don't need to save a reference to `this` - just access it directly in class methods. The way you have it at the minute, all your instances of CustomControlController are sharing a single `self` variable.

```
class CustomControlController {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    click() {
        var newValue = this.value * 2;
        this.value = newValue;
    }
}

export default CustomControlController;
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted the code, sorry.

The reason you'd want to save reference to self is for example in callbacks calling this might result in a different reference.
I was trying to do this:

```
    var self;
    class Test {
        constructor(dependency) {
          self = this;
          self.dependency = dependency;
        }
        method() {
            self.dependency().then(value => self.property = value);
        }
    }
```

Like it was mentioned before the self becomes shared when declared outside of the module. I didn't realize that would happen as files would be wrapped in a closure. Joe Clay answer is correct, but to do what I was trying to do self needs to be declared in every method that needs it.

```
    class Test {
        constructor(dependency) {
            this.dependency = dependency;
        }

        method() {
            var self = this;
            this.dependency().then(value => self.property = value);
        }
    }
```